# How to group an javascript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, grouping, reduce

I have a javascript array object from a database input like this:

```
 [{ date: '2021-09-15', type: 'cats', value: 4 },
  { date: '2021-09-15', type: 'dogs', value: 5 },
  { date: '2021-09-16', type: 'cats', value: 1 },
  { date: '2021-09-16', type: 'dogs', value: 4 }]
```

And I need an output like this:

```
 [{ date: '2021-09-15', cats: 4, dogs: 5 },
  { date: '2021-09-16', cats: 1, dogs: 4 }]
```

I am trying to use the reduce function by this way, however, I can't get it to work (it's grouping the data but not modifying it thus, they are left with a single value)

```js
const data = [
  { date: '2021-09-15', type: 'cats', value: 4 },
  { date: '2021-09-15', type: 'dogs', value: 5 },
  { date: '2021-09-16', type: 'cats', value: 1 },
  { date: '2021-09-16', type: 'dogs', value: 4 }
]

const groups = data.reduce((groups, item) => {
  const key = item[item.date];
  if (!groups[key]) {
    groups[item.date] = []
  }

  if (item.type == "cats") {
    item.cats = item.value;
  } else if (item.type == "dogs") {
    item.dogs = item.value;
  }

  groups[item.date].push(item);

  return groups;
}, {});

console.log(groups)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If second object with same `date` and already existing `type`. This also covers the case where you have multiple objects with same `type` then it will add up the `value`

```js
const arr = [
  { date: "2021-09-15", type: "cats", value: 4 },
  { date: "2021-09-15", type: "cats", value: 5 },
  { date: "2021-09-16", type: "cats", value: 1 },
  { date: "2021-09-16", type: "dogs", value: 4 },
];

const map = new Map();
arr.forEach((o) => {
  const { date, type, value } = o;
  if (!map.has(date)) map.set(o.date, { date, [type]: value });
  else {
    const target = map.get(date);
    const { type: newType, value: newValue } = o;
    target[newType] = target[newType] ? target[newType] + newValue : newValue;
  }
});

const result = [...map.values()];
console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really a two-step process...

1. Collect the data grouped by `date` into a map
2. Transform the final result into the array you want

```js
const data = [{"date":"2021-09-15","type":"cats","value":4},{"date":"2021-09-15","type":"dogs","value":5},{"date":"2021-09-16","type":"cats","value":1},{"date":"2021-09-16","type":"dogs","value":4}]

const t1 = performance.now()

const mapped = data.reduce((map, { date, type, value }) => {
  // get the current entry for date, default to `{}`
  const obj = map.get(date) ?? {}
  
  // merge and set the new entry
  return map.set(date, {
    ...obj,
    [ type ]: (obj[type] ?? 0) + value
  })
}, new Map())

const groups = Array.from(mapped, ([ date, obj ]) => ({
  date,
  ...obj
}))

const t2 = performance.now()

console.log(groups, `\nTook ${t2 - t1}ms`)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

It wasn't clear from your question but this answer sums up any same type values for the same date.